# como puedo hacer una cadena de conexión que pueda editar

Tags: c#

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto en C#

Trabajo en 3 capas y con una base de datos `mysql` la base de datos la trabajo con procedimientos almacenados(Rutinas).

Quisiera hacer un formulario en donde pueda configurar una cadena de conexión a mi base de datos siempre que yo lo quiera, pero no encuentro la forma de hacerlo.

Me gustaría que esta información se guardara en una variable del sistema, que cuando se vuelva a abrir el programa este guardado todavía.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Esto lo podes guardar en el archivo de configuracion de tu sistema. Busca sobre eso.

Comment: podrias usar el webconfi de c# y agrega una variable que sea tu cadena de conexión,esto se guarda en un xml externo a tu programa, lo que hará que puedas editar la cadena de conexión cuando gustes, en este link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595288/reading-a-key-from-the-web-config-using-configurationmanager hay un ejemplo de como acceder a las variables

Comment: La pregunta carece de la información básica para poder ser respondida. De todas maneras, si te refieres a cadenas de conexión a bases de datos, no dejes de darte una vuelta por https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-string-builders

Answer (score -2):

el código seria lo siguiente para que puedan cambiar la cadena de conexión .
para que se configure te he realizado un ejemplo con conexion a SQL SERVER pero con mysql es igual suerte y espero haberte ayudado.

```
string variableentrada="PIERO-PC";
string base ="base1";

SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection("server="+variableentrada+" ; database="+base+"; integrated security = true");
            conexion.Open();
```

Comment: No esta preguntando esto.. esta preguntando como persistirla ;)

Comment: Y ojo porque las cadenas de conexion son muy diferentes entre distintas bases...

Comment: Fijate que la línea `string base ="base1";` va a producir error.. si queres usar una palabra reservada agregale `@` antes `string @base = ...`